# Command for finding process using too much CPU

Tags: linux, shell, operating-system, cpu

What command can I use to find a process that's using a lot of CPU? Can I do this without installing something new?

Comment: Try `top`.  It's usually installed.  Also, this question is off-topic for Stack Overflow.  Try SuperUser.com.

Answer (score 17):

Or using a few other utils you could do:

```
ps aux | sort -rk 3,3 | head -n 5
```

Change the value of head to get the number of processes you want to see.

Comment: This can just be `ps aux --sort=-pcpu | head -n5` but if you want to use sort you should include the `-n` (numeric) option otherwise `6.5` will be higher than `32.5`. Otherwise, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Try doing this :

```
top -b -n1 -c
```

And if you want the process that takes the most %CPU times :

```
top -b -n1 -c  | awk '/PID *USER/{print;getline;print}'
```

or

```
top -b -n1 -c  | grep -A 2 '^$'
```

Comment: On my system, the last two commands consistently give me `top` as the command using the most CPU :)